# Unable to create a snapshot

Tags: xcode, snapshot

after looking for similar posts, I was unable to find a solution that worked for me. Whenever I try to create a snapshot, I get this error:

**Unable to write to info file DVTFilePath:0x40333f360:'/Users/Home/Library/Developer/Xcode/Snapshots/Projectname-fjjxrqffjieitcfaybymhrbrjxkr.xcsnapshots/info.plist'>**

After searching for a while I found this blog: [xcode-unable-to-create-snapshot-plist](http://blog.aitrus.com/2013/01/04/xcode-unable-to-create-snapshot-unable-to-write-to-file-plist/)

Basically states that deleting Xcode and re-installing it solved his problem. Is anybody have a different solution? Thank you.

Comment: is your user account named "Home" or did you just change that word for the question? if you go to Terminal and type in "`cd`" plus that path to get to the Snapshots directory, what are the permissions for the directory?

Comment: It is Home, I didn't change it. Using ls -ld /Users/Home/Library/Developer/Xcode/Snapshots , drwxr-xr-x.

Comment: I solved it.. The owner of the blog I referred to was right. Sometimes you just need a clean start. Everything works like a charm now!=)